# VBA to Hide and Unhide Rows using an activex check box

Tags: vba, excel, hide, rows

Can someone help me make this more efficient?  It is running around 10 seconds.  Thanks much!

I've adapted this code to hide rows that contain "Hide" as the result of a formula in column A of my worksheet.

```
Sub Hide_Rows()

 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 With ActiveSheet
For Each cell In .Range("a7:a115")
 If cell.Value = "Hide" Then
 cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 End If
 Next
 End With
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

I have a similar Show_Rows sub that unhides the hidden rows.  I have linked the button result (True or False) to cell A1 and then I'm using an If statement to either Hide_Rows or Show_Rows in the check box VBA

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
If Cells(1, 1).Value = True Then
     Hide_Rows
 Else
    Show_Rows
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This runs in less than 1 second for me. It's hard to say what might be causing lag on your end, other than possibly some very complicated worksheet formulas if they are being re-calculated at runtime.

Comment: I do have a bunch of complicated formulas that could be causing the performance issue.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Try disabling the calculation at the beginning of the procedure, then re-enabling it at the end of the procedure.

Comment: I was able to do that, thanks much

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be with lots of complicated formulas like David Zemens says. You have the right idea with the `Application.Calculation` but it should be `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the start, and then `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end.